# R Studio Fatal error: 'R_TempDir'contains space

Tags: r, windows

I tried to download the latest version (4.2.0) of R on my windows computer and received this error message upon trying to open the program.  "Fatal error: 'R_TempDir' contains space". Has anyone ever had this issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it? I have tried reinstalling the program and moving where the program is stored but no luck.

Comment: Note that v4.2.0 is the current version of R, not R Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also experienced this issue with 4.2.0 of R on Windows 10 but not prior versions of R.

In my case, the reason was the default temporary file folder was within my user directory and my user ID has a space in it. Apparently this causes an issue.

I was able to work around it by setting the global environment variable TMPDIR in windows:

1. Go to the search box next to the start button and type "environment"
2. Click on the choice which says "Edit the system environment variables"
3. Click the button that says "Environment Variables" near the bottom of the window
4. Click "New" and enter TMPDIR for variable name and some suitable directory without spaces under variable value (I chose C:\Temp)

As an aside, I do not believe this is an RStudio specific issue (and 4.2.0 isn't a version for RStudio anyway).

Comment: See this answer for additional help https://stackoverflow.com/a/73885683/11153608

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Venk for your post. It didn't work for me, but it pointed me in the direction of a solution that did.

I changed the values of my TEMP and TMP variables to a folder that had no spaces in it or in any folder name in the path (as you note).

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine.

Rob

P.S. My first solution was to revert to an earlier version of R, which initially worked. Recently though, I got the same error, even using a previous version. I'm no expert, but the whole thing is very weird IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and the other proposed solutions didn't resolve it for me.  (R 4.2.2 and Windows 10.)

[Solution found here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/uyej0c/fatal_error_r_tempdir_contains_space_in_420/) worked for me:

1. create a file named `renviron.site` that contains the following text, and save it to the Desktop, using a text-editing program.

   1. `TMP=C:/Temp TEMP=C:/Temp TMPDIR=C:/Temp`
   2. if a copy already exists, may need to handle that case-by-case
2. move the file to `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.x\etc`

   1. I wasn't able to save directly to this folder, despite being in the admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other solutions and none worked.  I came across [this post](https://lcolladotor.github.io/2019/09/18/windows-user-space-issues-with-installing-r-packages/#.Y92ryRXMLmE) that suggested to not install R in the /Program Files/ folder, to instead modify the installation to the folder C:\R\ which worked.

I didn't go back and undo the work done based on previous suggestions, so I'm not sure if they too are needed.